# Need help doing this view on swift

Tags: ios, swift

I came here to get some help.. I have to do this view on swift

[image]

I can't show nothing when I run the app, but I don't know if I'm doing it well... Can I do this view with a collectionView?

```
import UIKit

class DetalhesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()     
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "detalhesDaUC", for: indexPath) as! DetalhesCollectionViewCell;

        cell.ano.text="2"
        cell.codigo.text="9119213"
        cell.ects.text="6"
        cell.ucSigla.text="AED"
        cell.semestre.text="S1 - 1ºSemestre"

        cell.turno1.text="PL1 - Docente: carlos.urbano"
        cell.turno2.text="PL2 - Docente: joao.f.ramos"

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: Set DetalhesViewController as collectionview delegate

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't see a reason to implement this with collectionView since you return 1 for for the number of items in section.

I would place everything in a container view that can be placed in a ScrollView and connect corresponding UI elements with IBOutlets to your ViewController.

Since there is no native RadioButton in iOS, you can make use of the selected state of UIButton and change the image according the state of the button.